# How to make deep copy of Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching

I'd like to make a copy of class, while updating all of its methods to refer a new set of `__globals__`

I was thinking something like below, however unlike `types.FunctionType`, the constructor for `types.UnboundMethodType` does not accept `__globals__`, any suggestions how to work around this?

```
def copy_class(old_class, new_module):
  """Copies a class, updating __globals__ of all methods to point to new_module"""

  new_dict = {}
  for name, entry in old_class.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(entry, types.UnboundMethodType):
      entry = types.UnboundMethodType(name, None, old_class.__class__, globals=new_module.__dict__)
    new_dict[name] = entry
  return type(old_class.name, old_class.__bases__, new_dict)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__dict__` values are functions, not unbound methods. The unbound method objects only get created on attribute access. If you *are* seeing unbound method objects in the `__dict__`, something weird happened with your class object before this function got to it.

Comment: I'm not seeing unbound methods in my dict....should I just copy FunctionType elements of "dict" like regular functions?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Yes, since they are regular functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you, but I generally don't like to use `types` for anything other than type checking (which I don't do very often ;-).  I'd much rather `inspect`...

I have to preface this code by saying that I hope you have a really good reason for wanting to do this ;-) -- to me, it seems like just subclassing and overriding class properties should get the job done much more elegantly ...  However, If you really want to copy a class -- Why not just execute it's source again in the new namespace?

I've put together the following simple modules:

```
# test.py
# Just some test data
FOO = 1

class Bar(object):
  def subclass_method(self):
    print('Hello World!')

class Foo(Bar):
  def method(self):
    return FOO
```

And then something to do the heavy lifting:

```
import sys
import inspect

def copy_class(cls, new_globals):
    source = inspect.getsource(cls)
    globs = {}
    globs.update(sys.modules[cls.__module__].__dict__)
    globs.update(new_globals)
    exec source in globs
    return globs[cls.__name__]


# Check that it works...
import test

NewFoo = copy_class(test.Foo, {'FOO': 2})

print NewFoo().method()
NewFoo().subclass_method()

print test.Foo().method()
test.Foo().subclass_method()
```

This has some possibly desirable properties and undesirable... First, it only works on classes that are inspectable.  That's pretty much anything user-defined so probably not *too* restrictive... It also might be a bit slower than other solutions that don't involve re-parsing the source string -- But again, it doesn't seem like this should be executed *too* frequently, so that's probably Ok.

Now the "advantages"...

1. If a global is requested by a function but not supplied, this will use the global from the old namespace.  If this behavior isn't desireable (i.e. you'd rather have the `NameError`), you can modify the function easily to remove it.
2. The "copy" doesn't inherit from the original.  For most purposes, that probably doesn't matter, but it's a bit weird to have the copy of something inherit from the original ...

---

Some people might see the `exec` in here and immediately think "Oh no!  `exec`!?!?! The world is about to end!!!".  Franky, that's a good default response.  However, I argue that if you're copying a function that you plan to use later in the code, it is no more safe than using `exec` (after all, the function's code has already been executed).